# How to remove class from all elements jquery

Tags: jquery

I am changing the class of an element with the following

```
  $("#"+data.id).addClass("highlight")
```

Given the list below.

```
 <div id="menuItems"> 
 <ul id="contentLeft" class="edgetoedge"> 
 <li  class="sep" ">Shakes and Floats</li> 
 <li id="297"><a href="#" onClick="cart('297','add')"><small>$5.00</small><b>Vanilla</b>     </a></li> 
 <li id="298"><a href="#" onClick="cart('298','add')"><small>$5.00</small><b>Peanut Butter</b></a></li> 
 <li id="299"><a href="#" onClick="cart('299','add')"><small>$5.00</small><b>Combo</b></a></li> 
 <li id="300"><a href="#" onClick="cart('300','add')"><small>$5.00</small><b>Chocolate</b></a></li> 
 <li id="301"><a href="#" onClick="cart('301','add')"><small>$5.00</small><b>Strawberry</b></a></li> 
 <li id="303"><a href="#" onClick="cart('303','add')"><small>$5.00</small><b>Banana</b></a></li> 
 <li id="304"><a href="#" onClick="cart('304','add')"><small>$5.00</small><b>Root Beer Float</b></a></li> 
 <li id="305"><a href="#" onClick="cart('305','add')"><small>$5.00</small><b>Espresso</b></a></li> 
 </ul>
 </div>
```

I assumed I could remove the class with this...

```
  $(".edgetoedge").removeClass("highlight");
```

But this doesn't work. How can I remove the class?

Answer (score 187, accepted):

You need to select the `li` tags contained within the `.edgetoedge` class.  `.edgetoedge` only matches the one `ul` tag:

```
$(".edgetoedge li").removeClass("highlight");
```

Answer (score 46):

try: `$(".highlight").removeClass("highlight");`. By selecting `$(".edgetoedge")` you are only running functions at that level.

Comment: Your answer should be accepted. A very interesting trick, you save my day.

Answer (score 22):

This just removes the `highlight` class from everything that has the `edgetoedge` class:

```
$(".edgetoedge").removeClass("highlight");
```

I think you want this:

```
$(".edgetoedge .highlight").removeClass("highlight");
```

The `.edgetoedge .highlight` selector will choose everything that is a child of something with the `edgetoedge` class and has the `highlight` class.

Comment: +1 for ability to target items without knowing the element type.

Answer (score 8):

You could try this:

```
 $(".edgetoedge").children().removeClass("highlight");
```

Answer (score 3):

```
$(".edgetoedge>li").removeClass("highlight");
```

Answer (score 2):

The best to remove a class in jquery from all the elements is to target via element tag. e.g.,

```
$("div").removeClass("highlight");
```