# How to find all div elements with specific class using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

In my JSP I have 3 `div` elements out of which 2 elements has `class` "shadow".

```
<div name="master" class="shadow">
..................................
</div>
<div name="child1" class="shadow">
..................................
</div>
<div name="child2" class="normalshadow">
..................................
</div>
```

Now in my java script, I want to find all the div elements which has class shadow and remove that class from those div elements. How can i do that ?

Comment: `$('div.shadow')`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to remove class from all elements jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5997960/how-to-remove-class-from-all-elements-jquery)

Answer (score 5):

Find all div with class `shadow` using `.` `$(".shadow")` and remove class use `.removeClass()` function please find below snippet for more info

```js
$('div.shadow').removeClass('shadow');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div name="master" class="shadow">
..................................
</div>
<div name="child1" class="shadow">
..................................
</div>
<div name="child2" class="normalshadow">
..................................
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

`$('div[class="shadow"]').removeClass("shadow")`

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Answer (score 0):

if you want both `<div class="shadow"></div>` and `<div class="normalshadow">` to be selected you can do this `$('div[class*=shadow]')`